Spinning top stabilisation for a type of aircraft/drone
Spinning tops use gyroscopic precession to be able to stay upright whilst spinning.
Would it be possible to use this phenomena to create a flying craft that would be stabilised by gravity and the gyroscopic forces?
Think of a spinning top upside down, the force due to gravity on it's point would now be replaced by thrust from a propeller pushing upwards, and of course the weight of the craft would be pushing down from that point. A large portion of the craft would rotate around the thrust axis to create gyroscopic forces to balance it.
Has this technique been used in any aircraft? I have been designing some drones that use this and have had some success but am struggling to work out the best position to put the majority of the mass which has a big affect on the overall design of the craft.

I believe I read something about there having been an experimental VTOL aircraft that used a central propeller to generate thrust, but I don't remember it using gyroscopic stabilization. The thing to consider would be the centripetal forces required to keep the aircraft rotating, which would be immense and might result in material failure in the fuselage.

When it comes to spinning tops:
What we are familiar with is cases where the dynamics is dependent on the spinning top being in a situation where it has grip.
Let me explain what I mean by that.
In the case of the motion of a spinning top we can group the various forms in two categories:

The tip of the spinning top that carries the weight is prevented from moving sideways
the tip can slide over the surface, but there is friction.

When sideways motion is prevented the resulting motion is gyroscopic precession
When the tip can slide you get that some of the kinetic energy is lost to friction. Depending on the geometry of the setup, and the amount of friction the spinning top may decay rapidly, or the spinning top may end up rotating vertically, not moving sideways in any way.
That is to say:
In the spinning top cases that we are familiar with there is always at least some grip.

An extreme example, a case that involves huge leverage, is application of gyro wheels in luxury yachts, where they are used to suppress roll.
For that application the orientation of the spinning gyro wheels is changed with very powerful actuators. Those actuators are as powerful as the hydraulic cilinders of an excavator.
Like any ship a yacht is always much longer than it is wide. The leverage that the gyro stabilization needs comes from the fact that to push the stern deeper, or to push the bow deeper, requires a huge amount of force. It requires much more force that it takes to counter-act tendency of the yacht to roll when there is a swell.

But in the case of an aircraft you don't have that kind of leverage. There is no mechanical connection with the ground. The orientation of an aircraft is changed by application of the flight control surfaces
I don't see a way of making addition of a gyro wheel worthwhile.
Let's say you would want to design a roll suppressing gyro system for an aircraft, analogous to what is constructed for yachts.
In order to obtain the leverage that you need you need high capability flight control surfaces to generate that leverage.
Well, if you still need high capability flight control surfaces then it is more efficient to control the orientation of the aircraft directly with application of the flight control surfaces.

My point is:
When a gyro wheel has no grip then there is no opportunity for the spinning motion to straighten out.
For instance, there is the motion pattern that is commonly referred to as 'Feynmans wobbling plate'
That motion pattern does not "self-stabilize".
(In air there is some air friction that will tend to drain energy from the wobbling motion, but without air the wobbling will continue forever.)
Every instance of motion being stabilized with the aid of a gyro wheel involves leverage from mechanical contact with a very, very large inertial mass.
